# Respuesta de un Ajax request a una sola variable - JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

hola amigos quiero almacenar la respuesta de un ajax en una variable js para poder usarla después. lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
                var sucursalesOBJ = $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/JSONSUCURSALES",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                   return response
                },

                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                    //$('#myModalLabel').append(`error: - ${err}`);
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(err);
                    alert(err + ': carrousel');
                }
            });
```

Cuando hago esto y llamo a la propiedad sucursalesOBJ.responseText desde la consola de browers

```
[{"id":1,"longitud":"-21.111111","latitud":"11.22222","sucursal":"Sucursal 1"},{"id":2,"longitud":"19.053430","latitud":"-98.223228","sucursal":"Sucursal 2"},{"id":3,"longitud":"19.153430","latitud":"-98.283228 ","sucursal":"Sucursal 3"},{"id":4,"longitud":"19.344777","latitud":"-97.9318907","sucursal":"Sucursal 4"}]
```

Pero si intento esto en código `console.log(JSON.parse(sucursalesOBJ.responseText));` me da un error

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Total que al final necesito esa respuesta en una sola variable.

Comment: Ya no necesitas usar  `JSON.parse()` porque tu respuesta ya es un json, además de que en el ajax defines o especificas que esperas obtener un json en `dataType: "json"`, igualmente usar `responseText` ya no va, porque la variable `sucursalesOBJ` le retornas el valor de la respuesta `response`.

Answer (score 0):

Primero declara una variable global, ( que no esté dentro de una función)

```
var sucursalesOBJ;
```

Después modifica tu función Ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Home/JSONSUCURSALES",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
           sucursalesOBJ =  response;
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            //$('#myModalLabel').append(`error: - ${err}`);
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(err);
            alert(err + ': carrousel');
        }
});
```

Y por último, tu variable ya es `JSON` porque en la petición `Ajax` pusiste  `dataType: "json"`, entonces, no le puedes volver a aplicar la función `JSON.parse`, esta función solo la aplicas si no hubieras puesto el `datatype` es decir, es para convertir texto a `JSON`